# Aptana opening file for write failed

Tags: aptana

I get the error "opening file for write failed" every time I try to upload a file.  I am running OS X Lion on my Mac.  Does anyone have any idea how to fix this error.  I can't find a fix anywhere online.  Thanks.

Comment: This error can be caused a lot of different problems. Permissions, connection errors, and bugs. I would suggest instead reporting a bug with your particular details.

Comment: I've already done that.  Thanks, Ingo.

Comment: For me a reboot has fit the Problem. Maybe some racecondition inside of Aptana.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem on my Windows machine with Eclipse and the Aptana 3 Plugin. Turning off the Windows Firewall resolved it immediately!

Comment: start-> search programs [windows defender] -> tools -> administrator -> untick first option... cheers mate, worked a charm

Answer (score 5):

netsh advfirewall set global StatefulFTP disable

RUN THIS COMMAND IN cmd.exe, you can find more about it here

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771920(v=ws.10).aspx

IF YOU ARE USING WINDOWS 7(x64) AND APTANA 3.6.0 +, AND FILES FROM REMOTE SERVERS DO NOT OPEN !!

source : 
https://aptanastudio.tenderapp.com/discussions/problems/3252-opening-file-for-read-failed

Comment: Thanks sir you are a life saver :)

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem coming up because of files/directories permissions on the server. I'd do as suggested by Ingo above (reporting a bug with your particular details), as the message is rather cryptic.

Answer (score 0):

For me it appears for newest Aptana 3.4.2 for FTPS connections. Turning back to use FTP helped me.

Just in case that somebody has similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and by mistake I selected the wrong protocol, instead SFTP I took FTPS, which caused that problem... With FTP it works too.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem. After a lot of researching, i couldn't find a solution. I tried all what you recommended. I just right click in folder->publish->deplyment settings, then click on "more options" and set "Connect Mode" to Active. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this happens when the server discs are full. Its worth checking.